# CreateJS hit only visible elements

Tags: shapes, createjs, easeljs, hit

I have two shapes in my canvas using CreateJS. In each shape I included a hit area with the own shape with a mouseover listener. Two shapes are one above the other. When I click into the shape, I received the two callbacks. It's possible to get only the callback to the visible shapes?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go3uF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the DOM, the way mouse interaction works is to bubble up the display list, which excludes elements that are not part of the hierarchy chain of the event target.

This means siblings, or elements of other display lists that are underneath will not receive event handlers (which is what you described), and you will not receive mouse events for elements that are not the target of the mouse event.

However, you can wire up your own interaction fairly easily using `getObjectsUnderPoint`, which tells you what is under the mouse.

```
stage.on("click", handleClick);
function handleClick(event) {  
  var list = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(event.localX, event.localY);
  for (var i=0, l=list.length; i<l; i++) {
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}
```

Here is a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/y8jhb26x/

Note that you can add the mouse event to any container you want to constrain what objects will trigger this check (I just used stage), but when you call `getObjectsUnderPoint`, it will return *anything* under the mouse. If you want to only check items in that container, you can use the `contains` method to filter out unwanted children:

```
for (var i=0, l=list.length; i<l; i++) {
  if (someContainer.contains(list[i])) {
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}
```

You can also use arguments on `getObjectsUnderPoint` to filter out items with mouse handlers, or respect the `mouseChildren/mouseEnabled` property, which is how actual mouse interaction works.

- [getObjectsUnderPoint method](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_getObjectsUnderPoint)
- [mouse interaction code](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/files/easeljs_display_Stage.js.html#l721)

Hope that helps!